# Show contact name when composing email

Tags: ios, email

When sending an email to a recipient selected from the user's Contacts, is it possible for the name to show instead of the email address in the MailComposeViewController?

I would like for the user to select one or more recipients from a list drawn from the contacts and for my app to pre-populate that list of recipients before showing the MailComposeViewController and then for their names, not their email addresses to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to field is basically an array with one or more strings. You can do the following:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"My Name <myname@example.com>"]]
```

Careful the display name can't be more than 40 characters.

Comment: That doesn't show the MailComposeViewController. I want the names to show there.